# Prediction/time series/data problem

Tags: r, time-series, missing-data, data-imputation, interpolation

I have a poverty dataset with rows containing different places and different years and I have to predict the poverty percentage for those places next year.

Overall I have over a thousand rows. But I don't have enough data points for each of the places. Actually, the max data point I have for each of the places is only 2.

Obviously, time series isn't very likely. I tried linear interpolation to increase my data points but that wasn't very reliable. I'm also looking into imputation.

Right now, I'm looking into `predict()` of R, but I'm not sure that can actually give me anything that will also consider the year.

Any suggestions as to how to deal with this problem?

Comment: `stats::predict` is a generic function, it doesn't do any actual prediction by itself. You pass it a model object and it will compute the prediction for that model. If you pass in a time series model it will "consider the year". This isn't so much a question about R, you just need to find a good model for this situation (many related, very short time series) which will allow you to share information about the dynamics across series.